# Simple For loop confusion

Tags: python, scope

I am confused as to why the following code (particularly the `for` loop part) isn't working as intended:

```
sum = 0

def numberofdays ():
    for i in range (1901, 2000):
        if i%4 == 0:
            sum = sum + 366
        else:
            sum = sum + 365


sum = sum + 365 #to account for year 2000.

print sum
```

The `sum` value is returning 365, but it *should* be returning the total number of days between the years 1901 and 2000 - a number much larger than 365!

Comment: that's a matter of scope

Comment: (also, why do you need a loop for that?)

Comment: Just FYI: there were 366 days in the year 2000. Believe me - I didn't miss a birthday that year

Comment: Yep.  The rule is 366 days in years divisible by 4, except for years divisible by 100 *but not* divisible by 400.  So 2100 would have 365 days, but 2000 (being divisible by 400) had 366.

Comment: Python scope is LEGB (local, enclosing, global, built-in); you are using a global variable - unless it is a constant it is probably a bad idea, mutating global variables is a classic code-smell. Instead, just initialize sum inside the function and return it when you are done. Also, the name `sum` is a bad choice for variable name because it shadows a built-in.

Comment: Gah so much to learn. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining `sum` outside of the function and you are not calling it. Therefore, `sum = sum (0) + 365` which is correct in the eyes of the program, but not what you're looking for. You probably want:

```
sum = 0

def numberofdays ():
    sum = 0
    for i in range (1901, 2000):
        if i%4 == 0:
            sum = sum + 366
        else:
            sum = sum + 365
    return sum


sum = numberofdays() + 365 #to account for year 2000.

print sum
```

There is a discrepancy there between the two `sum` variables. They are different! You can read up on variable scope [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/).

Also, as noted by @Chris_Sprague, you should change the name of sum since it is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

**Here's an updated version:**

```
n = 0

def numberofdays ():
    total = 0
    for i in range (1901, 2000):
        if i%4 == 0:
            total = total + 366
        else:
            total = total + 365
    return total 


n = numberofdays() + 365 #to account for year 2000.

print n
```

Comment: There is a checkmark under the up or down button that you can click on. Clicking on it will mark the question as accepted and give the person an additional reputation score.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mySum = 0

def numberofdays ():

    global mySum # fix scope issues

    for i in range (1901, 2001): # fix Y2K (index) issue
        if i%4 == 0:
            mySum = mySum + 366
        else:
            mySum = mySum + 365


mySum = numberofdays()

print(mySum)
```

My addition to the other 2 answers already submitted is that you shouldn't call your variable `sum`, as it's a [built-in function in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Here's a (subjectively) nicer way to do it, avoiding global variables and making your code a bit more flexible:

```
# NOTE: does not include endYear in the calculation
def numberOfDays(startYear, endYear):
    sumOfDays = 0
    for yearNum in range(startYear, endYear):
        if yearNum % 4 == 0:
            sumOfDays += 366
        else:
            sumOfDays += 365
    return(sumOfDays)

myNumberOfDays = numberOfDays(1901, 2001)
print(str(myNumberOfDays))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of *variable scope*. Your function can't change the variable `sum` declared outside of it (although it can read its value). Try this:

```
sum = 0

def numberofdays ():
    global sum
    for i in range (1901, 2000):
        if i%4 == 0:
            sum = sum + 366
        else:
            sum = sum + 365


sum = sum + 365 #to account for year 2000.

print sum
```

Comment: @Gong No problem! If one of these answers helped you, it would be great if you could accept it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a while loop ;p

```
def numberofdays ():
    a=0
    c = 1901
    while True:
        if c < 2001:
            c+=1
            a += 365
            continue
        else:
            print('The number if days between 1901 and 2000 is ',a )
            break


numberofdays()
```